# Should the data-visualization and figure tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should the `data-visualization` and `figures` tags be merged?

There is no wiki description for `figures`, and the tag only has 2 questions.

Comment: These two cases are barely related to data-visualization. The tag [tag:figures] is a bad choice, IMHO. I would rather be inclined to delete this tag for those two questions.

Comment: Tags removed. I made a synonym `figure` <-> `data-visualisation` for future use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I vote yes; I don't see much point in having a lot of finely-differentiated tags. It will make it harder for people to find things later.

Comment: +1. If this is a vote, I'd also say yes. There are many other examples of tags like this on the site and there aren't enough active people to get the whole tag synonym thing to work well.